# Why is the standard deviation described as $\sqrt{pqn}$ sometimes and sometimes as $\sqrt{\frac{pq}{n}}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, variance

I assume it has something to do with whether we start with a distribution or with samples, but why is the standard deviation increasing with $n$ in one case and decreasing in the other?

Comment: Can you provide more description, i.e., how did you end up with that formula and how did you find out about the other formula/what do you think it represents?

Comment: Please add details. Confidence interval for what?

Comment: The difference between the standard deviation of the sum and the standard error of the mean, namely a factor of $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful!  $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum x_i$ has a $1/n$.

For $x_i\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)$, $\mathbb{E}\bar{x}=p$, and $\operatorname{Var}(\bar{x})=n^{-2}\operatorname{Var}(\sum x_i)=n^{-2}\cdot npq=\frac{pq}n$ if $x_i$s are independent.

Comment: Thank you! Could you also show me how in normal distributions we get $Var = pqn?$

Comment: @Asfangen The $x_i$ are iid so that $\mathsf{Var}(\sum_ix_i)=\sum_i\mathsf{Var}(x_i)=n\mathsf{Var}(x_1)=npq$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution

Also, this says the variance is supposed to be pq only

Comment: @Asfangen you are confusing $\operatorname{Var}(\sum x_i)=npq$ with $\operatorname{Var}(x_i)=pq$.  $\sum x_i$ is a Binomial(n,p), not Bernoulli(p).